# Python printing problems

Tags: python

```
print "I will now count my slaves:"

print "females", 50 + 80 \ 10
print "males", 10 \ 2
print "Is it true that 6 > 7?"
print "What is 59 + 27?"
```

For some reason, it shows me:

```
    print "females", 50 + 80 \ 10
                                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Answer (score 6):

The `\` character is a line continuation character, not the division operator. It is normally used to tell Python to join lines together:

```
foo = "This is a long line that won't fit inside 80 characters " \
      "so the line continuation character is one way to extend " \
      "the logical line across multiple physical lines."
```

Use `/` for division:

```
print "females", 50 + 80 / 10
print "males", 10 / 2
```